# I want to to create a file .json which contains php vars?

Tags: javascript, php, json

I want to create a file named "file.json.php"

Which contains vars from PHP like $_POST['foo'].

This file will generate diferents results depending on the value of the value of post var passed by an ajax call.

What configurations are necessary to make an ajax for call  file.php.json and how can pass an array as parameters to json file?

```
jqxhr = $.ajax('../files/data/file.json').
```

This is the Json file.

```
{
"data": [{
    "work": "Symfony No. 3 in D minor",
    "id": "1",
    "composer": "Anton Bruckner"
}, {
    "work": "Violin Concerto in E minor",
    "id": "2",
    "composer": "Mendelssohn Felix"
}, {
  "work": "Symfony No.1 in C major",
  "id": "3",
  "composer": "Beethoven, Ludwig van"
}, {
    "work": "Solution for dynamic headers in datatables",
    "id": "4",
    "composer": "Fasani, Guza"
  }],
"columns": [
                    {
                        "data": "work",
                        "name": "Work"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "id",
                        "name": "Product ID"

                    },
                    {
                        "data": "composer",
                        "name": "Composer"
                    }
            ]
   }
```

Comment: sure it is, but why aren't you using a database for this?

Comment: "This is my Json file"  So are you trying to _create_ a JSON file, or are you trying to _use/read_ a JSON file to produce some other results?

Comment: effectively this is a json for pupulate a table for datatable

Comment: Hi, @PatrickQ, i'm trying to generate a json file to put dinamic content. with some of this vars `<? $_POST['foo']; ?>`

Comment: As it stands, this question is too broad. The answer to any "Is it possible to ..." question is almost always "Yes". You need to make some sort of attempt to achieve your goal and see how far you can get. What you get stuck on something _specific_, feel free to post a question with the code that you're using, what the expected result is, what the actual result is, and what debugging you've already done.

Comment: thanks now i change my question for clarification.

Comment: The primary point of my previous comment stands.  _Make an attempt_.  There are plenty of guides on making ajax requests.

Comment: Please read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i made a file end-named with the php extension file.json.php, and manage it like a php normal file but adding an echo with the function json_encode().

This is a extract of how i made  the file.

```
  //only making to arrays an array (in this case for datatables dynamic columns on the fly)

    $columns[] = array("data" => "id", "name"=>"Id");
    $columns[] = array("data" => "number", "name"=>"numeroItem");
    $columns[] = array("data" => "item", "name"=>"Item");

    $a = array();
    $a['id'] = $row[$k]['id'];
    $a['number'] = $row[$k]['number'];
    $a['item']= $row[$k]['Item'];


    $data[] = $a;

    $json_for_datatable = array("columns" => $columns, "data" => $data);

    echo json_encode($json_for_datatable);
```

For configuration or considerations is necessary to receive de responseText with the function JSON.parse(),  ¡This is important!

```
data = JSON.parse(jqxhr.responseText);
```

For considering in the ajax call

```
var data,
            tableName = '#exampleTablaDinamica'+$(this).attr("data-id"),
            columns, str,
            jqxhr = $.ajax('../files/data/data.json.php?idPartida='+$(this).attr("data-idpartida")+'&meses='+ selected +'&idPresupuesto='+$('#idPresupuesto').val())
                    .done(function () {
                        data = JSON.parse(jqxhr.responseText);
            // Iterate each column and print table headers for Datatables
            $(tableName + " thead").html("<tr></tr>");

            $.each(data.columns, function (k, colObj) {
                str = '<th>' + colObj.name + '</th>';
                $(str).appendTo(tableName+'>thead>tr');
            });
            // Add some Render transformations to Columns
            // Not a good practice to add any of this in API/ Json side



            data.columns[0].render = function (data, type, row) {
                return data;
            }
            data.columns[1].render = function (data, type, row) {
                return data;
            }
            data.columns[2].render = function (data, type, row) {
                return "<a href='a.php'>" + data + "</a>";
            }

            // Debug?
            console.log(data.columns[0]);

            if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable(tableName) ) {
              $(tableName).DataTable().destroy();

            }


            table = $(tableName).dataTable({
                "data": data.data,
                "columns": data.columns,
                "responsive":true,
                "fnInitComplete": function () {
                    // Event handler to be fired when rendering is complete (Turn off Loading gif for example)
                    console.log('Datatable rendering complete');
                }
            });

        })
        .fail(function (jqXHR, exception) {
                        var msg = '';
                        if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                            msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                            msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                        } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                            msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                        } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                            msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                        } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                            msg = 'Time out error.';
                        } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                            msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                        } else {
                            msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                        }
            console.log(msg);
        });
```

And finally this is the generated JSON content.

```
{
"columns": [{
    "data": "id",
    "name": "Id"
}, {
    "data": "number",
    "name": "number"
}, {
    "data": "item",
    "name": "Item"
}, {
    "data": "10 2018",
    "name": "10 2018"
}, {
    "data": "11 2018",
    "name": "11 2018"
}, {
    "data": "total",
    "name": "total"
}],
"data": [{
    "id": "1",
    "number": "1.1",
    "item": "loremipsum  loremipsum  loremipsum  loremipsum  ",
    "10 2018": "0",
    "11 2018": "0",
    "total": "20.741"
}]
}
```